# DropdownChoice selected not the same as model value, being changed on ajax update

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have a listview and inside that listview is an

EnumdropDrop - Textfield - DropdownChoice - Ajaxbutton | for every item

The first dropdown is a currency and the second is an Account object, one of the choices in the account dropdown is to create a new Account which is then named after the currency.

When the new account is created is should be the selected value in the account dropdown.

This works fine for the first account, but the second and all subsequent newly created accounts are created correct and added to the list of possibilites but they are not the selected account. Everytime i make an ajax refresh the selected account in all newly created items are set as the first created account. The funny thing is when i submit the form, the account selections are correct.

```
package com.trifork.pengeplan.web.components.lists;

import com.trifork.pengeplan.domain.*;
import com.trifork.pengeplan.web.components.choice.EnumDropDownChoice;
import com.trifork.pengeplan.web.components.choice.OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListItem;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.PropertyListView;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.ResourceModel;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: tommysadiqhinrichsen
 * Date: 21/09/12
 * Time: 11.55
 */
public class MultipleCurrenciesListView extends PropertyListView<FinanceAccountCurrencyMapping> {

    IModel<OwnedAccount> ownedAccountIModel;

    public MultipleCurrenciesListView(String id, IModel model) {
        super(id, new PropertyModel<List<FinanceAccountCurrencyMapping>>(model, "financeAccountCurrencyMappings"));
        ownedAccountIModel = model;

    }

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem<FinanceAccountCurrencyMapping> item) {

        EnumDropDownChoice<MoneyCurrency> moneyCurrency = new EnumDropDownChoice<MoneyCurrency>("moneyCurrency");
        moneyCurrency.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                MoneyCurrency moneyCurrency = (MoneyCurrency) getFormComponent().getModelObject();
            }
        });
        item.add(moneyCurrency);

        item.add(new TextField("financeAccount.accountNumber"));

        final OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice accountForCash = new OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice("accountForCash", ownedAccountIModel.getObject().getLegalEntity().getOwnedBankAccounts());

        accountForCash.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                OwnedAccount ownedAccount = (OwnedAccount) getFormComponent().getModelObject();
                if (ownedAccount != null && ownedAccount.getId() == -1) {

                    OwnedAccount newOwnedAccount = new OwnedAccount();
                    FinanceAccountCurrencyMapping financeAccountCurrencyMapping = item.getModelObject();
                    financeAccountCurrencyMapping.setAccountForCash(ownedAccount);

                    newOwnedAccount.setName(financeAccountCurrencyMapping.getOwnedAccount().getName() + " - " + financeAccountCurrencyMapping.getMoneyCurrency().name());
                    newOwnedAccount.setLegalEntity(financeAccountCurrencyMapping.getOwnedAccount().getLegalEntity());
                    newOwnedAccount.setAssetOrLiability(AssetOrLiability.ASSET);
                    newOwnedAccount.setAssetType(AssetType.BANK_ACCOUNT);
                    newOwnedAccount.setCurrency(financeAccountCurrencyMapping.getMoneyCurrency());
                    newOwnedAccount.getFinanceAccountCurrencyMappings().add(new FinanceAccountCurrencyMapping(newOwnedAccount));
                    ownedAccountIModel.getObject().getLegalEntity().getOwnedAccounts().add(ownedAccountIModel.getObject().getLegalEntity().getOwnedAccounts().size() - 1, newOwnedAccount);

                    accountForCash.setDefaultModelObject(newOwnedAccount);

                    target.add(getFormComponent().getForm().getPage());

                }


            }
        });
        item.add(accountForCash);


        item.add(new AjaxButton("deleteFinanceAccount", new ResourceModel("button.delete")) {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                ownedAccountIModel.getObject().getFinanceAccountCurrencyMappings().remove(item.getModelObject());
                target.add(this.getForm());
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                super.onError();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Can someone tell me what the problem is?

[image: Created first account]
[image: Created second account]
[image: About to create third account]
[image: Created third account but not selecte]
[image: Refresh reset all]
[image: Saved values from image 5]

UPDATED

```
package com.trifork.pengeplan.web.components.choice;

import com.trifork.pengeplan.domain.OwnedAccount;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.ChoiceRenderer;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.ResourceModel;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: tommysadiqhinrichsen
 * Date: 18/09/12
 * Time: 16.01
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice extends DropDownChoice<OwnedAccount> {

    public OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice(String id) {
        super(id);
        List<OwnedAccount> choices = (List<OwnedAccount>) getChoices();
        choices.add(new OwnedAccount(-1, new ResourceModel("create.new").getObject()));
        setChoices(choices);
        init();
    }

    public OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice(String id, IModel model) {
        super(id, model);
        List<OwnedAccount> choices = (List<OwnedAccount>) getChoices();
        choices.add(new OwnedAccount(-1, new ResourceModel("create.new").getObject()));
        setChoices(choices);
        init();

    }

    public OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice(String id, List<OwnedAccount> choices) {
        super(id, choices);
        List<OwnedAccount> choices1 = (List<OwnedAccount>) getChoices();
        choices.add(new OwnedAccount(-1, new ResourceModel("create.new").getObject()));
        setChoices(choices);
        init();
    }

    public OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice(String id, List<OwnedAccount> choices, ChoiceRenderer<OwnedAccount> renderer) {
        super(id, choices, renderer);
        List<OwnedAccount> choices2 = (List<OwnedAccount>) getChoices();
        choices.add(new OwnedAccount(-1, new ResourceModel("create.new").getObject()));
        setChoices(choices);
        init();
    }

    public OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice(String id, Model<OwnedAccount> model, List<OwnedAccount> choices, ChoiceRenderer<OwnedAccount> renderer) {
        super(id, model, choices, renderer);
        List<OwnedAccount> choices3 = (List<OwnedAccount>) getChoices();
        choices.add(new OwnedAccount(-1, new ResourceModel("create.new").getObject()));
        setChoices(choices);
        init();
    }

    public OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice(String id, PropertyModel<OwnedAccount> model, List<OwnedAccount> choices, ChoiceRenderer<OwnedAccount> renderer) {
        super(id, model, choices, renderer);
        List<OwnedAccount> choices4 = (List<OwnedAccount>) getChoices();
        choices.add(new OwnedAccount(-1, new ResourceModel("create.new").getObject()));
        setChoices(choices);
        init();
    }


    public void init() {

    }

    public void addChoice(OwnedAccount ownedAccount) {

        List<OwnedAccount> choices = (List<OwnedAccount>) getChoices();
        choices.add(choices.size() - 1, ownedAccount);
        setChoices(choices);
    }
}
```

[image: Ajax response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem :)

Listviews are not good in forms because the can't handle dynamic changes because the list items dont keep track of their index.

I've implemented a listview based on a guide found at this website

http://wicketinaction.com/2008/10/building-a-listeditor-form-component/

I works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice does, it will be difficult to find the problem.

But please review this line:

```
new OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice("accountForCash",
  ownedAccountIModel.getObject().getLegalEntity().getOwnedBankAccounts());
```

Since you're modifying the bank accounts later on, this list might get stale.

Following the golden Wicket rule you should never pull something out of a model to put it into another:

```
new OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice("accountForCash",
  new PropertyModel(ownedAccountIModel, "legalEntity.ownedBankAccounts");
```

Perhaps this might help.

Comment: OwnedAccountCreateNewDropDownChoice is an extension of dropdownchoice. I have added the code above. i have tried you solution but the same thing happen. In the meantime i have locked at the ajax debugger in wicket. Something funny is happening with newly generated code send to the page. Plz see latest image.